# jQuery remove bootstrap alert after certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timeout

I am using dynamic bootstrap alerts from an example. See below.

How can I add a timeout function so alert closes automatically after **X** time ?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="alert_placeholder"></div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
bootstrap_alert = function() {
    }
bootstrap_alert.warning = function(message) {
    $('#alert_placeholder').append('<div class="alert alert-block fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><h4>Info!</h4>'+ message +'</div>');
}
bootstrap_alert.info = function(message) {
    $('#alert_placeholder').append('<div class="alert alert-block alert-info fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><h4>Info!</h4>'+ message +'</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a function that removes the first (hence, oldest) alert:

```
function alertTimeout(wait){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#alert_placeholder').children('.alert:first-child').remove();
    }, wait);
}
```

`[0]` to ensure that only the first alert gets removed, for each timeout.

And then call the function when you show the alert, with the parameter being how long until the alert closes, in milliseconds:

```
bootstrap_alert.warning = function(message) {
    $('#alert_placeholder').append('<div class="alert alert-block fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><h4>Info!</h4>'+ message +'</div>');
    alertTimeout(5000);
}
```

Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4391/)

Comment: this removes all the alerts at same time.
Lets say alert a was generated and then b . sequence of closing should be a then b. not a and b together.

Comment: except for using IDs is their a way before appending we can select '<div class="alert as selector so it closes its relevant alert ?

Comment: It throws error 
TypeError: $(...).children(...)[0].remove is not a function

Comment: If i use .children('.alert').first().remove(); it works but in reverse order .. first goes b and then a.

Comment: Very strange: still it closes alerts in reverse order
I tried using:  .find('.alert:first-child').remove();

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
$(function () {

 setTimeout(function () {
            if ($(".alert").is(":visible")){
                 //you may add animate.css class for fancy fadeout
                $(".alert").fadeOut("fast");
            }
        }, 3000)

});
```