# show bootstrap dismissible alert on button each click Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-5

I am creating a web application using Asp.net c#. I want to show alert on user each click.
The alert showing from top of the page, the second alert pushdown the first alert and it will close automatically on 5 seconds. Like as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiufN.jpg)

If user continually clicking the button then the alert will be continued and it will close automatically on 5 seconds

I have tried with the following link
[Bootstrap Alert Auto Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101966/bootstrap-alert-auto-close)
But its shows only one alert. If user continually clicking the button then the alert will be continued

Answer (score 0):

The type of message you are referring to is in general called a toast message.

I am not sure if bootstrap now has "toast" messages built in, but there are boatloads of sample routines that you can adopt for this purpose.

So, assuming you have jQuery, then grab the toastr example from here:

https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

So, some sample markup:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" 
            Text="toast test"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClientClick="mytoast('ToastHeading','Test toast message');return false;" />

        <script>

            function mytoast(head, mytext) {

                // head = heading part 
                // mytext = text in toast message to display

                $.toast({
                    heading: head,
                    text: mytext,
                    position: 'top-right',
                    icon: 'info',
                    hideAfter: 5000,
                    allowToastClose: false,
                    loader: false,
                    stack: 10,
                    showHideTransition: 'slide'
                });
            }

        </script>
```

And the result is this:

[image]